# Develop Mobile App using Angular js,C# Mvc mongodb

Tags: c#, android, angularjs, mongodb, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new in mobile Development. My project Architecture is On client side Angular Js, On server side C#Mvc(Use web API for communicating server) and db is mongodb.

Now i need to design mobile App with the help of above mentioned technologies. First question it is possible or not? Can we use any other tools to develop Apk files such as phonegap etc or Any other tools that are present in market to develop above architecture

If not then can you please guide me some ways that how i can design mobile App with help of Angular js ,C#mvc and Mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

You can develop hybrid mobile app using ionic framework.

```
http://ionicframework.com/
```

Some Features of ionic:

1) Based on Angularjs

2) Easy to use

You can use any language for server side to create api's.